# Change the value of a checkbox based on whether it's ticked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-generation

I'm making this text code generator, and I'm a bit stuck. In the customization panel you have 5 checkboxes. They are bold, italic, underline, strikethrough and obfuscate. They all have a value which is currently "false".

What I want to happen is that when a checkbox is checked, its value will be changed to "true". Why? When you get the code is does something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="false" id="bold"/>
<input type="button" value="Give Code" onclick="printCode()"/>
<script>
function printCode() {
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML= bold.value;
}
</script>
<p id="code"></p>
```

In this example, when the button is pressed, it'll print out the value of the checkbox. It'll always print out "false". I want it so that when you tick the checkbox, its value will be changed to "true". That way, when it goes to print out the value, it can be "true" or "false".

I am aware that jQuery may be the solution, but I'm very new to it.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the checked state, that will be true / false depending on wether or not the checkbox is checked, no need for a value ?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="false" id="bold" />
<input type="button" value="Give Code" onclick="printCode()" />
<script>
    function printCode() {
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bold").checked.toString();
    }
</script>
<p id="code"></p>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9RDH/)

Answer (score 1):

Use bold.checked instead of bold.value

```
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML= bold.checked;
```

If you still want to use bold.value, add onClick function to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bold" value="false" onclick="this.value = this.value == 'false' ? 'true' : false"/>
```